# How to create a 2d array of zeroes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Is there an easy way to programmatically create a 2d array in javascript?

**What I don't want:**

```
var array2D = [ 
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you could write a helper function:

```
function zeros(dimensions) {
    var array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; ++i) {
        array.push(dimensions.length == 1 ? 0 : zeros(dimensions.slice(1)));
    }

    return array;
}

> zeros([5, 3]);
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Bonus: handles any number of dimensions.

Comment: Change `item` to a lambda that is a factory for items.

Comment: This could be written much more clearly.  Typically when you're writing a recursive function, you should make sure that the base case and inductive case are easily identified.  In the code above, both are on the same line -- very confusing.  Instead, I would recommend that you check the `dimensions.length === 1` conditional at the top of the function and that you create two `for` loops -- one that creates an array of 0s (the base case) and one that creates an array with `zeros` function calls (the inductive case).  Though the resulting code will be more verbose, it's much less confusing.

Answer (score 77):

## Solution 2017:

Late to the Party, but this Post is still high up in the Google search results.

#### To create an *empty* 2D-Array with given size (adaptable for more dimensions):

```
let array = Array(rows).fill().map(() => Array(columns));
```

#### Prefilled 2D-Array:

```
let array = Array(rows).fill().map(() => Array(columns).fill(0));
```

E.g.:

```
Array(2).fill().map(() => Array(3).fill(42));
// Result:
// [[42, 42, 42],
//  [42, 42, 42]]
```

#### Warning:

`Array(rows).fill(Array(columns))` will result in all rows being the reference to the same array!!

### Update 24th September 2018 (thanks to @Tyler):

Another possible approach is to use `Array.fill()` to apply the map function.

E.g.:

```
Array.from(Array(2), _ => Array(3).fill(43));
// Result:
// [[43, 43, 43],
//  [43, 43, 43]]
```

#### Benchmark:

https://jsperf.com/multi-dimensional-array-map-vs-fill/5

Comment: Nice answer. Using  `Array.from({ length: rows }, () => Array(columns).fill(value));` instead of `Array.from(Array(rows), _ => Array(columns).fill(value));` would avoid creating the empty array. But I'm not sure which one is faster.

Comment: Richard Natal was nice enough to update the jsperf test for me, so I will just update the jsperf link. For me, the `[...Array(1000)].map(e => Array(1000).fill(0));` approach is the fastest, closely followed by the for-loop variant.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following function to create a **2D array of zeros**:

```js
const zeros = (m, n) => [...Array(m)].map(e => Array(n).fill(0));

console.log(zeros(3, 4));

// [ [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
//   [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
//   [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
function zero2D(rows, cols) {
  var array = [], row = [];
  while (cols--) row.push(0);
  while (rows--) array.push(row.slice());
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A no-frills, easy-to-understand method for beginners:

```
function twoDarrMaker(row, col) {
  const twoDarr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    let subarray = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      subarray.push(0);
    }

    twoDarr.push(subarray);
  }

  return twoDarr;
}

twoDarrMaker(3, 2);
// [
//   [ 0, 0 ],
//   [ 0, 0 ],
//   [ 0, 0 ]
// ]
```

Edit: Here's an explanation of my code. You create an array, `twoDArr`, to hold the 2d array, or array of arrays. You use the outer for loop to create subarrays. Then you use the inner for loop to add zeros to the subarray. Then you add the subarray to the outer array, `twoDarr`. Then you repeat the process however many times the outer for loop specifies. When the outer for loop is finished, you return the 2d array.

Basically, the outer for loop creates the rows (subarrays), while the inner for loop creates the columns (elements in the subarrays). The outer for loop tells you to create `x` rows (subarrays) by repeating the code in the block `x` times, and the inner for loop tells you to create `y` columns (elements) by repeating the code in the block `y` times.

Comment: Please, don't post code without an explanation as an answer. Try to explain what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.