# An array full of zeros

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a program in JavaScript where you input a number `n` and it returns an array `M` that is a list of length 'n' and each element of the list is a different list `ele` that is also length `n` and has every element equal to zero. This is my function:

```
var zeros=function(n){
    var M=[];
    var ele=[];
    for (var q=0; q<n; q++){
        ele.push[q]=0;
    }
    for (var p=0; p<n; p++){
        M.push[p]=ele;
    }
    return M;
};
```

My problem is that `ele` always remains undefined no matter how I try to change it. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: `ele.push[q]=0;` -> either `ele[q]=0;` or `ele.push(0);`. Same with `M.push[p]=ele;`

Comment: Actually after a second look `M.push[p]=ele;` shouldn't be done that way at all because you'll assign *the same* array to every index in `M`. The easiest thing is to make `Array.from({length: n}, () => Array(n).fill(0))`

Comment: [How to create a 2d array of zeroes in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3689903)

Comment: Oops, guess I just forgot how `.push` works. :)  My bad. Thanks

Comment: `const zeros = (n) => { const M = []; for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) { const ele = new Array(n); ele.fill(0); M.push(ele); } return M; }`

Comment: Something like `const zeros = (n) => Array.from({length: n}, () => Array(n).fill(0))` should do.

Comment: You say "`ele` always remains undefined".  You're not returning it.  That variable only exists while the function is running.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use push like this Array.push[x]. if you use push on an array it always puts that item to the end of the array (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp). so you can use:

ele.push(0);

OR

ele[q] = 0

Answer (score 0):

1. [create a non sparse Array of custom length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#using_arrow_functions_and_array.from)
2. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each array item (the undefined value) into

   - 2a) [a new sparse Array of custom length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#array_constructor_with_a_single_parameter)
   - 2b) immediately [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)ed with the custom `value`.

```js
function squareMatrix(n, value) {
  return Array

    // creates a non sparse, thus iterable, array 
    // which features n-times the undefined value.
    .from({ length: n })

    // thus, one can map over each item.
    .map((item, idx) =>

      // creates a sparse array of custom length `n` which
      // immediately after gets filled with the custom `value`.
      Array(n).fill(value)
    );
}

console.log(
  'squareMatrix(2, 0) ...',
  squareMatrix(2, 0)
);
console.log(
  "squareMatrix(3, '')",
  squareMatrix(3, '')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```