# Modifying value of matrix filled with Array.fill() modifies the whole column

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a matrix A, of dimension n*n, initialized with `Array.fill()` like so.
`var A = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(0))`

That's cool and all however if I try to modify one of its values, the whole column modifies instead.
`A[2][3] = 1` modifies the whole column 3.

Example snippet :

```js
var n = 4;
var A = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(0));
console.log(JSON.stringify(A));

A[2][2] = 4;
console.log(JSON.stringify(A)); // ...
```

Why is that? o.O

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a 2d array of zeroes in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689903/how-to-create-a-2d-array-of-zeroes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is bacause your first `Array.fill` call is using the same array reference to fill those 4 spots and only one inner array is created. So instead of first fill call you could use `Array.from` which is going to create new array for every spot.

```js
var n = 4;
var A = Array.from(new Array(n), () => new Array(n).fill(0))
console.log(JSON.stringify(A));

A[2][2] = 4;
console.log(JSON.stringify(A)); // ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Per MDN, [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

> If the first parameter is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object.

That is if the value you're filling the array with is an object, all elements will reference the same object and not a copy of the array

```js
const n = 4;
const array = new Array(n);
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) array[i] = new Array(n).fill(0);

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));

array[2][2] = 4;

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```