# push function in Array() constructor adds it to all elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am facing very weird problem here with `Array constructor` in JavaScript. I declare an array with length 5 which further contains arrays. When I want to push an element in the first sub-array, it adds that element in all sub-arrays.

```js
var items = new Array(5).fill([]);
items[0].push(1);
console.log(items.toString());
```

It gives `1,1,1,1,1`, but I am expecting `1,,,,`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66623300/modifying-value-of-matrix-filled-with-array-fill-modifies-the-whole-column

Comment: `new Array(5).fill([]);` puts the **same** array (`[]`) in all five slots in `items`. Since it's the **same** array, any changes to its state are apparent regardless of which reference to that array you use to look.